# Terraform - Rescource group already exists even though part of backend with terraform apply

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I've extended my terraform definitions which I run via an Azure pipeline. The terraform init task has a backend configuration on the pipeline which defines the resource group medquality-aks but it seems there is an issue. I am not even sure though since there are 3 errors at once.

Earlier I thought there was a permission issue so I added the create permission to the Microsoft Graph API for terraform.

The resource group does not exist before running the pipeline though.

```
2020-12-30T20:30:05.2720640Z [0m[1mrandom_id.log_analytics_workspace_name_suffix: Creating...[0m[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:05.2726774Z [0m[1mrandom_string.sp-aks-password: Creating...[0m[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:05.2763813Z [0m[1mrandom_string.sp-aks-secret: Creating...[0m[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:05.2769915Z [0m[1mrandom_string.sp-aks-password: Creation complete after 0s [id=i<50H)EbQENB::#nf>Z4Af@k][0m[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:05.2786026Z [0m[1mrandom_id.log_analytics_workspace_name_suffix: Creation complete after 0s [id=qByINuQDrlg][0m[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:05.2806341Z [0m[1mrandom_string.sp-aks-secret: Creation complete after 0s [id=kLLI(=aZ4K[+%kN[%xay-E9h][0m[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:05.5417261Z [0m[1mazuread_group.aks_administrators: Creating...[0m[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:05.5463857Z [0m[1mazuread_application.sp-aks: Creating...[0m[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4043339Z [0m[1mazurerm_resource_group.mq-aks: Creating...[0m[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4519178Z [31m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4521407Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mgraphrbac.ApplicationsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Unknown" Message="Unknown service error" Details=[{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","date":"2020-12-30T20:30:05","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"27125e18-2100-43b3-970b-9be30bed427e"}}][0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4522796Z 
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4523723Z [0m  on aks-ad-sp.tf line 11, in resource "azuread_application" "sp-aks":
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4524357Z   11: resource "azuread_application" "sp-aks" [4m{[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4524725Z [0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4524971Z [0m[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4525228Z [31m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4526780Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mcreating Group ("aks-administrators"): graphrbac.GroupsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Unknown" Message="Unknown service error" Details=[{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","date":"2020-12-30T20:30:05","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"30882842-8926-4eee-8d45-847759849087"}}][0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4528021Z 
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4528543Z [0m  on aks-administrators-group.tf line 1, in resource "azuread_group" "aks_administrators":
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4529197Z    1: resource "azuread_group" "aks_administrators" [4m{[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4529531Z [0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4529922Z [0m[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4530174Z [31m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4531284Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mA resource with the ID "/subscriptions/ae250472-5313-4abf-a081-3f746e68c88f/resourceGroups/medquality-aks" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_resource_group" for more information.[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4532029Z 
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4532489Z [0m  on aks-rg.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "mq-aks":
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4532999Z    1: resource "azurerm_resource_group" "mq-aks" [4m{[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4533300Z [0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4533543Z [0m[0m
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4545723Z 
2020-12-30T20:30:09.4679091Z ##[error]Terraform command 'apply' failed with exit code '1'.:  graphrbac.ApplicationsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Unknown" Message="Unknown service error" Details=[{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","date":"2020-12-30T20:30:05","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"27125e18-2100-43b3-970b-9be30bed427e"}}] |  creating Group ("aks-administrators"): graphrbac.GroupsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Unknown" Message="Unknown service error" Details=[{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","date":"2020-12-30T20:30:05","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"30882842-8926-4eee-8d45-847759849087"}}] |  A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/ae250472-5313-4abf-a081-3f746e68c88f/resourceGroups/medquality-aks" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_resource_group" for more information.
2020-12-30T20:30:09.9560347Z ##[section]Finishing: terraform apply
```

The permissions I've currently set for the API:

[image: Azure API permissions]

Update:

After dealing with some issues on how to create a service principal I know have an issue on the role assignment provisioning, the previous issues seem fine now, is that a matter of policy roles? I didn't see anything in the hashicorp documentation though:

```
2021-01-05T02:32:19.0757008Z [0m[1mazurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool.user: Creation complete after 4m10s [id=/subscriptions/ae250472-5313-4abf-a081-3f746e68c88f/resourcegroups/medquality-aks/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/medquality-aks/agentPools/user][0m[0m
2021-01-05T02:32:19.0846822Z [31m
2021-01-05T02:32:19.0853022Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mauthorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '0595a82d-0ef5-4dce-a526-a348ad51ce6d' with object id '0595a82d-0ef5-4dce-a526-a348ad51ce6d' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/ae250472-5313-4abf-a081-3f746e68c88f/resourceGroups/medquality-aks/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/medquality-aks-network/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/c81c31c4-fa80-d98b-887f-b1d44852e7ce' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."[0m
2021-01-05T02:32:19.0855355Z 
2021-01-05T02:32:19.0856617Z [0m  on aks-rbac.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sp-aks-network":
2021-01-05T02:32:19.0858454Z    1: resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sp-aks-network" [4m{[0m
2021-01-05T02:32:19.0858855Z [0m
2021-01-05T02:32:19.0859142Z [0m[0m
2021-01-05T02:32:19.1005049Z 
2021-01-05T02:32:19.1063551Z ##[error]Terraform command 'apply' failed with exit code '1'.:  authorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '0595a82d-0ef5-4dce-a526-a348ad51ce6d' with object id '0595a82d-0ef5-4dce-a526-a348ad51ce6d' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/ae250472-5313-4abf-a081-3f746e68c88f/resourceGroups/medquality-aks/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/medquality-aks-network/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/c81c31c4-fa80-d98b-887f-b1d44852e7ce' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
2021-01-05T02:32:19.4811396Z ##[section]Finishing: terraform apply
```

Comment: `Code="Unknown"` `Message="Unknown service error"` `"Authorization_RequestDenied"` `"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."` -  sounds like you / terraform is missing permissions / privileges. In terms of resources already existing, you need to either delete the resource manually and run terraform again or `import` it, look at the terraform docs for that.

Comment: The issue you mentioned was due to a remaining group in the tf files. Now I need to create the azuread_group and find the proper permission to do so,

Comment: Hi @1174. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT I tried today but I seem to miss the "Select the APP(used to create Azure Devops Service connection)" as I haven't needed one for the terraform pipeline. I have terraform under "Owned applications" and have set the permissions as outlined but I assume that was not right, where would I use the Service Connection and map it to the terraform pipeline I've been using?

Comment: When you using azure pipeline to  extend my terraform definition, are you using the service connections? If yes, it will generate a app in App registrations. You need to grant  permissions for the app.

Comment: OK, thank you. I have several applications in the form of CompanyName-ProjectName-ProjectHash which assumingly map to the pipelines. Am I able to find out which actual pipeline it is as I have several pipelines in one project?

Comment: I also encountered this situation before.  This is because you created the service connection through the Service principal (automatic).  In this situation, the name are same , but the id is different.You can try to use Service principal (manual) method to create a service connection in azure devops. This will be clear.

Comment: On the other hand, you can also distinguish them by creation time, or you can create a new service connection, and the newly generated app is the corresponding app.

Comment: Thank you @KevinLu-MSFT, I made some progress, now I have permission issues on the role level, I updated my ticket, how do I find the roles I need to set actually? I did not find it in hashicorp documentation, do I need to check ARM documentation?

Comment: Hi @1174 Have you granted the permissions to service principal? You can follow up the steps in the answer and check if it could work. From the latest log, it seems that this issue is similar to the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ##[error]Terraform command 'apply' failed with exit code '1'.:  graphrbac.ApplicationsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403

According to the error information it indicated that you have no permission to do that.

You could refer to this doc about [terraform permission](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/application):

> If you're authenticating using a Service Principal then it must have permissions to both **Read and write all (or owned by) applications** and **Sign in and read user profile** within the Windows Azure Active Directory API.

You need to grant the **Azure Active Directory Graph** premission instead of **Microsoft Graph** permission.

You could navigate to `Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> Select the APP(used to create Azure Devops Service connection) -> API permissions -> Azure Active Directory Graph`.

Delegated permissions ->  Sign in and read user profile(**User.Read**)

Application permissions ->  Read and write all (or owned by) applications (**Application.ReadWrite.All**) and  Read and write directory data (**Directory.ReadWrite.All**)

In addition, you can also grant this App **Contributor role** in the subscription.

Here is the doc about the detailed steps to [grant Contributor role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal).

Comment: Thank you @Kevin Lu-MSFT, the last step was to assign the owner role on the service principal for the azurerm_role_assignment resource but your answer helped me to find the right path for sure. I must say the permissioning is quite cumbersome in Azure, the only part so far that I can say. For example the service principal can only be found for role assignment by providing the full name. But yeah, part of the game.

Comment: Great ! Glad to know that you have found the method to solve this issue.  I have indeed experienced the same problem you mentioned(e.g.  providing the full name), so I feel the same as you.

Comment: On the other hand, if the answer could give you some help, you may consider accepting it as answer. Thanks.